# null model in glmnet

Tags: r, glmnet

With `lm` models I can construct a null model like this:

```
lm(y ~ 1, data=df)
```

What would the equivalent be in `glmnet`?

The idea would be to compare the performance of my actual model with that of the most basic model I can define.

Comment: Why would an intercept-only model not be an appropriate null model?

Comment: @Roland, but what would an intercept-only model look like in a glmnet call? `glmnet(matrix(rep(1,length(y))), y)` won't work because `x` must be a matrix with at least 2 columns...

Comment: Why do you need to fit it with `glmnet`? Why do you need a null model at all to access performance?

Comment: I have a model fit with `glmnet`, performed cross-validation, extracted MSEs, but I have nothing to compare them with. So the idea was to run `glmnet` on a null model and compare it with my actual model, so that I can evaluate if my actual model is good enough.

Comment: For example, MSEs may all be around 1.80 (with small variance) after cross-validation my glmnet model , but what does that really tell me without some sort of baseline?

Comment: Root mean squared errors have the same unit as your dependent variable and tell you how close predicted values are in average to observed values. So, if you observed height of people with a mean of 1.7 m and SD of 0.2 m, having a RMSE of 0.01 m would tell you that predictive performance is quite good.

Comment: @Roland, thanks I get it now. `if you observed height of people with a mean of 1.7 m and SD of 0.2 m`: Should I compute the observed mean/SD for the entire sample, and then compare it with mean RMSE across all folds? Or does that have to be done within each fold?